# Dropshadow in a a transparent .png not rendering correctly on iOS device

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, transparency

I am using the following image as the image property for a UIImageView.  It is semitransparent with a semitransparent drop shadow.  When I display this view, it is rendered above a video with a white background.  The drop shadow is not visible.  When I take a screenshot from the device, the shadow shows up in the image.  It seems like something is going wrong when the image is drawn, or the contrast is off on the device.  The other interesting thing is that it looks fine on the simulator.  Any ideas on why this is happening?

[image: shadowed window]

EDIT: I've tried cleaning the build.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1.delete your app in the device

2.in xcode menu:build:clean (and clean all targets)

3.in your project folder delete the folder "build"

it happens sometimes that xCode doesn't refresh the new images or other resources files when we modify them...
i lost a lot of time looking for code errors... to discover that it was just a bug in xCode compile/copy resource process...

hope this could be your case too...

luca

Comment: I've been bitten by this before, so it was one of the first things I tried.  Thanks, though!

Comment: @michael: the strange is that it's ok on the simulator... one other thing that is different in simulator is that files are not case-sensitive (but they are on Devices). so, if your png file name is "aD5eu.png" and you load via code calling "ad5eu.png" it will be loaded in simulator, but it won't in iPhone... no other ideas right now...

Comment: Just double checked that.  It's beeing loaded, it's more like the white behind the shadow is "too bright" and renders the shadow invisible.  I suspect that making the shadow darker will make it visible.  It's inconvenient that a design might necessarily hold up on the device, even it looks good in photoshop and the simulator.

Comment: yeah, right... it's the dark side of the wonderful display of our iDevice... a bit of more work to do for us... good luck